# Inductive proof on a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-writing, induction, computer-science

I had a quiz today with an inductive proof that gave me some trouble.
Given a sequence $a_n=\begin{cases}1,n=1\\3,n=2\\a_{n-2}+2a_{n-1},n\ge3
\end{cases}$
prove that all the values are odd.

So I was confused if I should use mathematical induction or strong induction.
I started with M.I. and made it this far, but I'm stuck and do not see where I have to go.

PF,

(Base Case) when $n=3$

$a_3=a_1+2a_2=1+2(3)=7$ So our base case holds.

(Inductive Hypothesis)

Assume True for $n=k$, $a_k=a_{k-2}+2a_{k-1}$, for $k \ge 3$

(Inductive Step)

Show for $n=k+1$,  $a_{k+1}=a_{(k+1)-2} +2a_{(k+1)-1}$

$a_{k+1}=a_{k-1} +2a_{k}$

$a_{k+1}=a_{k-1} +2(a_{k-2}+2a_{k-1})$   By our inductive hypothesis

This is where I get confused. I'm not sure what step to take next, or if I am using the wrong form of induction all together. I tried to multiply it out and combine the terms, but I am still lost. Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You are overthinking this a bit.  Just think about the parity (oddness or evenness) of $a_{n-2}$ and $2a_{n-1}$, and what happens when you add even + even, odd + even, or odd + odd.

Comment: Prove it instead by letting $P(k)$ be the statement "Both $a_k$ and $a_{k+1}$ are odd." Then $P(1)$ is true by definition. The induction step is also easy.

Comment: If the goal is to prove that all values are odd. Consider the last step you've written using the inductive hypothesis. What do you know about the parity of the $a_i$s and what can you say about the combination of their parities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use strong induction. First, note that the first two terms $a_1$ and $a_2$ are odd. Then, for $n\geq 3$, assume you know that $a_1, \ldots, a_{n-1}$ are *all* odd (this is the strong part of the induction).

- By definition, $a_{n} = a_{n-2} + 2a_{n-1}$.
- By the inductive hypothesis, $a_{n-1}$ and $a_{n-2}$ are both odd.
- If we know that $2\times \mathsf{odd} = \mathsf{even}$, then we can additionally know that $2a_{n-1}$ is even.
- If we know that $\mathsf{odd} + \mathsf{even} = \mathsf{odd}$, then we can additionally know that $a_{n-2}+2a_{n-1}$ is odd.
- Hence $a_{n} = a_{n-2} + 2a_{n-1}$ is odd, which completes the induction.

---

P.S. Here's a thinking tool: The reason I thought strong induction would be the right approach is that the formula for $a_n$ not only refers to the element right before ($a_{n-1}$), but *two* elements before $(a_{n-2})$, and so it seemed easier if I could assume that *all* earlier elements had the inductive property.

Comment: Thank you for this answer! It makes much more sense to do it this way and I understand your reasoning.

Answer (score 0):

Use strong induction. Suppose that $a_n$ is odd for all $n\leq k$. To see that the claim is true for $k+1$ note that the equation
$$
a_{k+1}=a_{k-1} +2(a_{k-2}+2a_{k-1})
$$
implies that $a_{k+1}$ is odd as you have an odd number, $a_{k-1}$ by the inductive hypothesis, plus an even number on the RHS.

Answer (score 0):

I would say use "strong induction"

That is when you state the inductive hypothesis. Say

Assume for all $k\le n,  a_k$ is odd.

It is true in the base cases $k=1, 2$ by definition.

And show that $a_{n+1} = 2a_{n} + a_{n-1}$ must be odd.

Sine $a_n, a_{n-1}$ are odd based on the inductive hypothesis we can say:

$a_{n} = 2i + 1, a_{n-1} = 2j + 1$ for some $i,j$

$a_{n+1} = (4i + 2j + 2) + 1$

Answer (score 0):

I personally dislike the insistence of distinguishing between "normal" and strong induction. If you prove something sequentially then you have necessarily proven it over previous cases. Once you internalize this fact, you won't ever have to wonder which version you need (you can always use strong induction, and if at the end you have only used the $k=n$ case then you just call it "normal" induction).

After you finish your base cases, consider $n+1$:
If the statement is true for all less than or equal to $n$ then there are integers $b$ and $c$ so that $a_{n-1} = 2b+1$ and $a_n = 2c+1$, then
$$a_{n+1} = a_{n-1} + 2a_n = (2b+1) + 2(2c+1) = 2(b+2c+1)+1 $$
which is odd.

Comment: More to the point would be to simply *prove* that "strong induction" is derivable from "normal induction", then you can just cite the result as a lemma when you perform "strong induction". (Though, to be clear, there are patterns of induction that are not so straightforwardly reducible to "normal" induction where you actually *won't* have proven the result for all smaller numbers yet.)

Comment: Thank you this helped me to better understand induction and wrap my head around this problem